# Running a block with dispatch_get_main_queue() doesn't work and hang the app

Tags: objective-c, ios

If a run a synch block with the function  : `dispatch_sync` using the queue retrieved from `dispatch_get_main_queue()` the application hang and the block is not executed, while if I pass the queue obtained from : `dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)` it works without any problem .

```
dispatch_queue_t q;
q = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

//q = dispatch_get_main_queue();  //If uncommented the app hang

dispatch_sync(q , ^{
    NSLog(@".");
});
```

Why using the queue obtained from `dispatch_get_main_queue()` cause the app to hang and the block doesn't get executed ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you synchronously dispatch to the main queue from the main queue, it *should* freeze. You're asking it to dispatch a block of code to the main queue, but because it's synchronous (`dispatch_sync`), you're asking it to freeze the current queue (the main queue) until the dispatched queue (also the main queue) responds to what you've just added to it! It obviously can't do that.

Either do `dispatch_async`, or dispatch to a different queue!

Comment: @user1590355 No offense, but I find that very unlikely. You might want to put another `NSLog` right before the dispatch, to make sure you're getting to the block of code you think you are. You should be able to `dispatch_async` to the main queue from the main queue (though that's obviously not a very common requirement!). I just did `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ NSLog(@"."); });` and it works fine. Perhaps you have some other `dispatch_sync` lingering about which is keeping the asynchronously dispatched code from running.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Rob's answer, here are the docs for Grand Central Dispatch ([programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091), [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html)).  It is a great set of libraries, and had made concurrency mostly painless, but it is not fool proof.